# DensityPlot help

Tags: plotting

I currently have this code,

```
psi = a (Sin[2*Pi*x] Sin[3*Pi*y] + .5 Sin[3*Pi*x] Sin[2*Pi*y]);
psip = Abs[psi]^2;
psipp = Integrate[psip, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
Solve[psipp == 1, a, Reals]
b = 0.894427;
psii = b (Sin[2*Pi*x] Sin[3*Pi*y] + .5 Sin[3*Pi*x] Sin[2*Pi*y]);
DensityPlot[psii, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-5, 5}}]
```

I now want the density plot to only show where my zeros are and positive and negative numbers. Like if its zero the color would be black, if positive, green, and if negative, red. Something like that. Does any one know how I would go about getting this done?

Thank you

Comment: Did you check `ContourPlot`? Note that you are not using `psip`, `psipp` and `Solve[...]` so there no need to overcomplicate the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
b = 0.894427;
psii = b (Sin[2*Pi*x] Sin[3*Pi*y] + .5 Sin[3*Pi*x] Sin[2*Pi*y]);
```

#### DensityPlot

```
DensityPlot[psii, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{{Red, Green}, {-2, 2}}, {-2, 0, 2}], 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-5, 5}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, psii], Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

#### ContourPlot

```
ContourPlot[psii, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{{Red, Green}, {-2, 2}}, {-2, 0, 2}], 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {-5, 5}}, Contours -> {{0}}, 
 ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], PlotPoints -> 100, 
 ContourShading -> {Red, Green}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why there is aliasing with `DensityPlot`?

Comment: @anderstood, good question; I don't know why.